# How can I join 2 tables so that I can use filters to query both

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, select, where-clause

I have 2 tables, one called 'ads' and one called 'users'. I have different data stored in each. The ads.ad_user column is populated using the users.user_id from the users table. How can I build a query so that I can filter data from both tables.

Here is the query that I built but it won't allow me to filter data from both tables independently.

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="ethnicity">ETHNICITY</label>
    <select class="form-control ethnicitySelect" id="ethnicity" onchange="searchFilter();">
        <option selected disabled>Ethnicity...</option> 
        <option value="ethnicityall">All</option>
        <option value="other">Other</option>                                                
    </select>
</div>
```

```
<div class="form-group" style="padding:5px;color:#333;">
    <label for="citySelect">LOCATION</label>
    <select class="form-control citySelect" id="citySelect" onchange="searchFilter();">                                     
        <optgroup label="State">
        <option disabled selected>Select A City</option>
    </select>
</div>


$querySelectCount = "SELECT COUNT(ads.ad_id) as rowNum,
            ads.ad_id,
            ads.ad_title,
            ads.ad_content,
            ads.ad_date,
            ads.ad_user,
            ads.ad_photo,
            ads.ad_photo_thumb,
            ads.ad_age,
            ads.ad_city,
            ads.ad_rate,
            ads.ad_plan,
            ads.ad_approved,
            ads.adminPost,
            users.user_id,
            users.username,
            users.user_picture,
            users.userAge,
            users.height,
            users.hair,
            users.ethnicity,
            users.eyeColor,
            users.type              

            FROM
                ads
            LEFT JOIN
                users
            ON
                ads.ad_user = users.user_id                 

            $usersSQL

            WHERE 
                ads.ad_approved = '0'               
            $adsSQL $orderSQL                   
            ";
```

Here are a couple of the filters I am using.

```
if(isset($_POST['city']) && !empty($_POST['city']) && $_POST['city'] !== 'null'){   
    $city = $filter->filter($_POST['city']);
    $whereSQL .= " AND ads.ad_city = :city "; 
}else{
    $city = 0;
    $whereSQL .= " AND ads.ad_city >= :city "; 
}


if(isset($_POST['ethnicity']) && !empty($_POST['ethnicity']) && $_POST['ethnicity'] !== 'null'){
    $ethnicity = $filter->filter($_POST['ethnicity']);
    if($ethnicity == "ethnicityall"){
        $whereSQL .= "AND users.ethnicity != :ethnicity ";
    }else{
        $whereSQL .= "AND users.ethnicity = :ethnicity ";
    }
}else{
    $ethnicity = 0;
    $whereSQL .= "AND users.ethnicity >= :ethnicity ";
}
```

I am using multiple dropdowns to filter the data, for example: When I select a city nothing will display until I select options that are from the users table like ethnicity or height or eye color...Actually, I need to select all of the above before any data will even be displayed. Would another SELECT inside the query help me achieve what I am looking to do?
Thanks.

Also Here is the filters I am applying
    [image]

And here is a pic of the query after selecting an item from the ads table and an item from the users table
    [image]

Here is the printout of the updated query

object(PDOStatement)#5 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(973) "SELECT COUNT(ads.ad_id) as rowNum, ads.ad_id, ads.ad_title, ads.ad_content, ads.ad_date, ads.ad_user, ads.ad_photo, ads.ad_photo_thumb, ads.ad_age, ads.ad_city, ads.ad_rate, ads.ad_plan, ads.ad_approved, ads.adminPost, users.user_id, users.username, users.user_picture, users.userAge, users.height, users.hair, users.ethnicity, users.eyeColor, users.type FROM ads **LEFT JOIN** users ON ads.ad_user = users.user_id AND users.ethnicity != :ethnicity AND users.eyeColor != :eyeColor AND users.hair != :hairColor AND users.height >= 0 **WHERE** ads.ad_approved = '0' AND ads.ad_city = :city AND ads.ad_rate >= 0 AND ads.ad_content LIKE :keywords ORDER BY ad_date DESC " }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you need to use LEFT JOIN instead of INNER, then you can add condition of users table to ON statement

```
LEFT JOIN users ON ads.ad_user = users.user_id AND users.ethnicity = :ethnicity
WHERE ads.ad_city = city
```

Then they will work independently

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Dmitry Reutov I have tried a LEFT JOIN but it does the same thing. I wonder if a UNION would be needed for this. I am using AJAX to update the query when a user makes a selection from one of the dropdowns.

Comment: @Stuckfornow, Trying it did you move the conditions of user to ON block from WHERE?

Comment: Please provide small example of primary data, filters you want to apply and result you want to get...may be i misunderstood the problem

Comment: @Stuckfornow, i dont see that users conditions you moved to ON block, it is still in WHERE block according your picture, even ads.user_id = user.id in WHERE block gut knows why

Comment: So your saying to add the 'AND' clause before the 'WHERE' clause in the query for the users table?

Comment: so I moved all the queries for the USERS table to $usersSQL and all values from ADS table to $adsSQL for WHERE clause...It will now filter all items from the ads table but none of the users table items like ethinicity or hair color, etc. get filtered out.

Comment: @Stuckfornow, please show your query test excluding select blick

Comment: ok, I updated the question with the query. Let me know if there is more info that you may need. thanks.

Comment: I cant see query text in your update, only php code, i ment sql text starting with Left join ...

Comment: oh sorry, I updated the question with the output of the query, hope that is what you were looking for.

Comment: @Stuckfornow, so you can see in your example no filters are set (everything is !=, which actually not needed, just dont add it if no filter) thats why it is not filtered out

Comment: Finally figured it out, and yes moving the query for the other table ahead helped as well. Thank you for your patience and help. It works great now. Issue was that I did not check for 'null' value instead I only checked for isset and empty values. Jquery was sending it as 'null' in quotes.